# Obtener propiedades de un JSON

Tags: java, android, json, parsear

Tengo este *JSON*, y quiero analizarlo en *Android*:

> {"usd":{"code":"USD","alphaCode":"USD","numericCode":"840","**name**":"U.S. Dollar","**rate**":0.062953567779141,"date":"Sun, 4 Dec 2016 12:00:01 GMT"},"eur":{"code":"EUR","alphaCode":"EUR","numericCode":"978","**name**":"Euro","**rate**":0.059052814030065,"date":"Sun, 4 Dec 2016 12:00:01 GMT"}}

Quiero obtener `name` y `rate`. No sé si debo crear un `JSONArray` así:

```
JSONArray objetoName = jsonObject.getJSONObject("name");
```

... o si ir al `String`.

```
for(int i=0;i<objetoName.length();i++){
    JSONObject stringer = objetoName.getJSONObject(i);
    stringArray[i] = stringer.getString("name");
}
```

Comment: Te has un par de detalles clave. **1.** El lenguaje en el que lo quieres parsear. **2.** El código que has intentado

Comment: @LosMilton gracias por editar tu pregunta, he agregado respuesta, como comento este json es un objeto que contiene dentro objetos, saludos.

Comment: Gracias a @ArtEze que se tomo el trabajo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu Json, es un objeto que contiene varios objetos, en este caso `usd` y `eur` :

> {**"usd"**:{"code":"USD","alphaCode":"USD","numericCode":"840","name":"U.S.
>        Dollar","rate":0.062953567779141,"date":"Sun, 4 Dec 2016 12:00:01
>        GMT"},
>
> **"eur"**:{"code":"EUR","alphaCode":"EUR","numericCode":"978","name":"Euro","rate":0.059052814030065,"date":"Sun,
>        4 Dec 2016 12:00:01 GMT"}
>   }

Lo que necesitas es obtener los objetos dentro de un objeto lo cual puedes realizar obteniendo los keys y mediante un Iterator obtener sus datos:

```
String valorName="";
String valorRate="";

   try {
            //    contenidoJson es tu string conteniendo el json.
            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(contenidoJson);
            //Obtenemos los objetos dentro del objeto principal.
            Iterator<String> keys = mainObject.keys();

            while (keys.hasNext())
            {
                // obtiene el nombre del objeto.
                String key = keys.next();
                Log.i("Parser", "objeto : " + key);
                JSONObject jsonObject = mainObject.getJSONObject(key);

                //obtiene valores dentro del objeto.
                valorName = jsonObject.getString("name");
                valorRate = jsonObject.getString("rate");

                //Imprimimos los valores.
                Log.i("Parser", valorName);
                Log.i("Parser", valorRate);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Parser", e.getMessage());
        }
```

Como resultado obtendrias:

```
Parser: objeto : usd
Parser: U.S. Dollar
Parser: 0.062953567779141
Parser: objeto : eur
Parser: Euro
Parser: 0.059052814030065
```

Comment: Creo que es un caso particular... Habría que hacer un `for` para obtener cada nombre de las divisas, en vez de probar solo con `"usd"`.

Comment: Amigo me he dado cuenta no es un objeto usd son varios diferentes, edito

Comment: El OP acaba de editar su pregunta.

Comment: El tema es que "usd"  debería ser un Array o no?...

Comment: @Elenasys ¿está mal hecho el Json?

Comment: @LosMilton Esta bien hecho, pero tiene una estructura diferente a lo común, en este caso es un objeto que tiene dentro objetos. Agregue respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Elenasys hoy estuve pensado y había llegado a lo siguiente:

Comment: necesitaba obtener
String nameUsd=jsonObject.getJSONObject("usd").getString("name");
String valorUsd=jsonObject.getJSONObject("usd").getString("name");
String nameCl=jsonObject.getJSONObject("clp").getString("name");
String valorCl=jsonObject.getJSONObject("clp").getString("name");

no lo pude probar

Comment: Que bien te sirvio @LosMilton saludos!

Comment: @LosMilton si es similar únicamente que regularmente no se escribe la obtención de cada elemento, eso se realiza en un loop, pero es similar, saludos!

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Si, es que soy medio bestia

Comment: Claro que no amigo al inicio hay cosas que se dificultan pero con practica veras que todo es mas sencillo, saludos.

Answer (score -2):

Si usas Gson lo que podes hacer es crearte un objeto que tenga como nombre y tipo de variables de instancia algo equivalente a lo que tenes en el json y luego podes deserializarlo usando los metodos que te provee gson [aca](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/gson-java-json/) explican muy bien como hacerlo. Espero haberte ayudad

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!